# Solve $pq^2=ax+by$ - a nonlinear first-order pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$p$ is $dz/dx$, $q$ is $dz/dy$

I've written down the Charpit's equations:

$\frac{dp}{a}=\frac{dq}{b}=\frac{dz}{3q^2p}=\frac{dx}{q^2}=\frac{dy}{2qp}$

But i'm clueless as to what to do next. I don't know why would anyone find these enjoyable and i'm totally clueless about what these equations would mean in the real world, but anyway, i would appreciate if someone helped me out with this.

Comment: 'I'm clueless as to what to do next'... Solve them \begin{align} dp/a &= dq/b \\ \implies bp &= aq + c_{1} \\ d(p + q)/(a + b) &= dy/2qp \\ \implies \dots \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the ODE $\frac{dq}{b}=\frac{dx}{q^2}$ is $q=(3bx+C_1)^{1/3}$. Since $q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$, it follows that
$$
z=(3bx+C_1)^{1/3}y+f(x). \tag{1}
$$
Substituting $(1)$ in the PDE
$$
pq^2=ax+by, \tag{2}
$$we obtain
$$
\left[b(3bx+C_1)^{-2/3}y+f'(x)\right](3bx+C_1)^{2/3}=ax+by
$$
$$
\implies f'(x)=ax(3bx+C_1)^{-2/3} 
$$
$$
\implies f(x)=\frac{a(bx-C_1)(3bx+C_1)^{1/3}}{4b^2}+C_2. \tag{3}
$$
Therefore,
$$
z(x,y)=(3bx+C_1)^{1/3}\left[y+\frac{a(bx-C_1)}{4b^2}\right]+C_2 \tag{4}
$$
is a complete integral of the PDE $(2)$.